# How to turn lists inside of a list into strings

Tags: haskell

I have a list that i partitioned with a function and I want to turn the lists inside of a list into strings.

list : [[0,0],[0,1]]

If i use show list, I will get "[[0,0],[0,1]]", which turns the whole list into a string. What output I want to get is ["[0,0]","[0,1]"], which turns only the objects inside the list into strings. I'm assuming I could use show in the function I use to partition the list but I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

The function that I am using

```
partition :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
partition n = go
    where go [] = []
          go xs = ys : go yss
              where (ys, yss) = splitAt n xs
```

I assumed I could just change [[a]] to [string], but that didn't work. I don't really have a clue on how I could even insert show in this function either.

Is there a way to use show but only on the objects inside a list? If not I'd like to get a tip on how to edit this function to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to use show but only on the objects inside a list?

Yes, you can just `map` the `show` function, to get a list of strings of the form that you say you want.

That is:

```
map show list
```

should give you what you're looking for.

Comment: Wow I cannot believe i forgot about map, I guess that goes to show how new I am to Haskell. Thank you so much.